# Return of async method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have async method:

```
public  async Task CreateAndWriteAsyncToFile()
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream("test.dat", FileMode.Create,FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, 4096, true))
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[100000];
                new Random().NextBytes(data);

                await  stream.WriteAsync(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

Compiler complains :

> The return type of async method must be void, Task or Task
>       not all code paths returns value.

How to solve this method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code, the issue seems that you have another `Task` type defined somewhere in your project. change the method signature to:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task CreateAndWriteAsyncToFile(){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, check if you did import the System.Threading.Tasks namespace. If you accidentally created a Task class (Visual Studio will suggest you to create a class if it doesn't exists) be sure to remove it.